# Auto get_header and get_footer on every template?

Tags: theme-development, headers, footer

Is there a way to automatically run `get_header()` at the beginning of template and `get_footer()` at the end of it?

Currently my code is too repetitive with those calls.

I've been looking for a way to do this, but I can't find it in Google.

Comment: Calling `get_header()` and `get_footer()` directly is the appropriate way to do it in your templates.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I see, if that's the recommended way I guess I should live with it. It's just that having `get_header()` on every single template file doesn't seem clean.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at `wp-includes/template-loader.php` … there seems to be a way:

```
if ( $template = apply_filters( 'template_include', $template ) )
    include( $template );
```

You could hook into that filter, handle the including in a callback function and return `FALSE`.

Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

    get_header();
    include $template;
    get_footer();

    return FALSE;
});
```

Comment: You're the man! This should be standard! THANKS A LOT

Comment: @DarcCode : I agree that these function calls should be more automatic but, while this may work for you, it does limit the flexibility of the individual template files-- that is, it becomes impossible to add code _before_ `get_header()` in a template file, which is sometimes quite convenient.

Comment: True that, I'm still learning wordpress, so I haven't made complex site yet. But in what case you need to put code before `get_header`?

Comment: I hadn't seen many use cases for stuff _before_ header, however these functions accept header/footer name argument for loading _different_ headers, which can be very much required in more complex sites.

Comment: @Rarst that's a good point to mention... The current example is limited in flexibility, you could extend it further adding your own filter to optionally pass in header($params)/footer($params).

Answer (score 3):

[@scribu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu) proposes a method for reducing code repetition in WordPress templates which he calls [theme wrappers](http://scribu.net/wordpress/theme-wrappers.html), which achieves what you're looking for. The [roots theme](http://roots.io/starter-theme/) uses a slightly modified [version of this method](http://roots.io/an-introduction-to-the-roots-theme-wrapper/).

Comment: Summary of the method would be nice to include in answer. Links die.