# How can I add some blocks to template without changing template file?

Tags: templates, child-theme

I'm working with the paid child Wordpress theme which I can not change because after it's update all my changes would be lost. I need to change post template (for castom post type, in my case it's *single-listing.php*). How can I add some blocks to template without changing template file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can - if you can't make a child of a child theme ( which I'm fairly certain you can't ) and the main theme doesn't supply any hooks - the only real thing you could do is [hook into `get_footer();`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_footer) but that may be too late.

Answer (score 0):

[Filter `template_include`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/142570/73), use output buffering to catch the rendered file content and [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to change it.

Untested example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {

    // Bail out early.
    if ( 'the-file-you-want-to-filter' !== $template )
        return $template;

    get_header();

    ob_start();

    include $template;

    $content = ob_get_clean();

    // See user notes on http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $content );

    // dirty fix
    foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item)
        if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
            $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
    $doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper  

    /**
     * Edit the file content here.
     */
    echo $doc->saveHTML();  

    get_footer();

    return FALSE;
});
```